# Swift Performance with instance property arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, performance

I've come across an interesting Swift performance problem, and was looking for some suggestions, analysis on why this is happening.

I have an algorithm that required hundreds of thousands of array accesses in a loop. I find that if I reference the array as an instance property (from inside the same class instance), the performance is very poor. It seems that the array is being de-referenced at each iteration. That seems strange given that the arrays are members of the *same* class doing the work. Wouldn't self.x not require x to be dereferenced over and over again? The equivalent Java code doesn't have the same performance problem.

In the below example, test3 takes 0.5 seconds and test4 takes 0.15 seconds.

Do I really have to go through all my code and assign locally scoped arrays every single time I do something?

Any tips/ideas would be welcome. I have the compiler optimization set to Fast-O.

Simon

EDIT: The answer is spelled out in this article here:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27

Hope it helps. Long story short, private/final for the class scoped variables will remove the need for the unwanted indirection to access the array.

```
class MyClass {

    var array_1 = [Int64] (count: 16 , repeatedValue: 0)
    var array_2 = [Int64] (count: 16 , repeatedValue: 0)


    func runTest3() {
        // test #3
        //
        let start = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        for i in 0 ... 10000000 {
            if (array_1[ i%16 ] & array_2[ i%16 ] ) != 0  {
                // whatever
            }
        }
        let passed = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - start
        print("3 time passed: \(passed)")
    }

    func runTest4() {
        // test #4
        //
        let start = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        let localArray_1 = self.array_1
        let localArray_2 = self.array_2
        for i in 0 ... 10000000 {
            if (localArray_1[ i%16 ] & localArray_2[ i%16 ] ) != 0  {
                // whatever
            }
        }
        let passed = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - start
        print("4 time passed: \(passed)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I compiled this with `-O` and got less than 0.01 seconds for each one. It probably depends what you do inside the loop.

Comment: If you do ...let localarray = self.array.. Swift doesnt copy the array, he just "points" to the memory and keeps the record of changes to the array (kind of like git is working) so it is save to use it this way

Comment: Yes, the localArray method is safe enough, it just prevents the self.??? dereference happening every iteration.

Comment: @jtbandes - I have -O set in Swift Compiler Code Generation, but I get this:

3 time passed: 0.44688892364502
4 time passed: 0.0145220756530762

Comment: Do you have any code replacing "whatever"?

Comment: I dont think you have to use "self.array" ...simply array is enough

Comment: Also the huge difference is that array-1 is var but in test4 they are constant "let" and this is probably the performance you are looking for

Comment: @jtbandes, yes but it should not affect the timing results. I put in a simple {x+=1}, same result. I wonder if you could zip up your project and email your project to me? seems you've configured to get the same result for both tests.

Comment: @SimonFox I literally copied & pasted your code into a .swift file, and added `import Foundation` + some calls to the runTest functions. Then I ran it from the command line with `swift -O test.swift`.

Comment: @MazelTov yes, whether typing self. or not is just a syntactical thing, does not affect the test. Either way, it's an array outside the scope of the function and appears to take a lot of effort to reference each iteration. Making a local pointer to the array (localArray_1) in the example, is a one-time dereference action, which appears to save a lot of time. From that point on, accessing the array is probably just an integer offset task. Wheras in test3, each array access seems to be: (1) dereference the array object inside "self", and (2) access the index by integer offset arithmetic

Comment: @jtbandes, ok thanks for the info. I'm running it from inside an XCode project. Wonder what's up with that

Comment: Seems that making the arrays private solves the problem. eg. private var array_1 (except that I might need them to be public)

Comment: I'm pretty sure @MazelTov is correct to suggest that the difference is that your properties are variables, but the local values are constants. The swift compiler can better optimize constants. I don't know much about low-level code, so I can't explain why, but that's what it is. I replaced your `var`s with `let`s, and the methods took exactly the same time. In fact, in some runs the `runTest3` was slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27

Private/Final for the class-scoped variables removes the performance problem. Reasons in the above article. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Looks like your link leads to this same question and not the post you've intended.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov - Ooops, thanks for picking that up. Fixed the link now. Late Sunday night brain freeze there. Cheers

Comment: This answer may be misleading users. As long as Whole Module Optimization is turned on (and it should be for Release mode), there is little need to mark methods final/private for performance reasons. These markings are to express your intent to other programmers. Please see the last section of the linked blog post about how WMO addresses this issue.