# Swift class, method and property restrictions

Tags: swift, restriction

I'm searching for a working compromise between readability / usability and performance improvements through code restrictions.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682450/swift-performance-with-instance-property-arrays/36685972#36685972) question and the linked Apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27) it seems to be very important to use code restrictions as often as possible.

On the other hand, I have never seen an example where all code restrictions are implemented and I would never try to code like this:

```
    final internal class TestClass {
        final private var result: String = "Result"
        ...

        final internal func TestMethod(result: String) -> String {
            ...
        }
    }
```

So is there a generally accepted and "working" compromise?

**EDIT**

In other words, if the performance improvement generated by code restrictions like `final` and `private` is as huge as mentioned in the attached article, why do we see it very rarely? And why isn't it the default behavior?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question (no comments) clarifying your question. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @rmaddy hope this edit help to understand me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer mis-states the linked blog post. If you're using Whole Module Optimization (which you should always be using in Release mode), you generally do not need to proactively add `final` or `private` for performance reasons. The compiler will figure out when they can be inserted. You should use `final` and `private` to express your intent to other programmers (and yourself), not the optimizer.

> However, if Whole Module Optimization is enabled, all of the module is compiled together at the same time. This allows the compiler to make inferences about the entire module together and infer final on declarations with internal if there are no visible overrides.